# download actionresult via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a File ActionResult via jQuery

```
$.get("/Home/DownloadAction")
```

and I can see that the method is being called but no prompt to download the file (no errors either)? Can someone please explain? Because if I make it

```
Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAction")
```

it works as expected.

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're trying to pull the data in the background using AJAX with the $.get() method.  I think you probably want something more along the lines of...

```
document.location = "/Home/DownloadAction";
```

to get the behavior you're looking for.